# Highcharts: "Print all" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, highcharts

Is it possible to create a "Print all" button for Highcharts, where more that one chart is printed?

I know that exporting multiple charts is possible, as demonstrated in the jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/gd7bB/1/ but I'm not sure Highcharts allows a similar method with printing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution that does the printing directly. It's based on the **chart.print()** function, but it works on multiple charts.

See the **demo** here: http://jsfiddle.net/jim31415/q5Rzu/150/

```
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        $("#print").click(function () {
            printCharts([chart1, chart2, chart3]);
        });


        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        function printCharts(charts) {

            var origDisplay = [],
                origParent = [],
                body = document.body,
                childNodes = body.childNodes;

            // hide all body content
            Highcharts.each(childNodes, function (node, i) {
                if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                    origDisplay[i] = node.style.display;
                    node.style.display = "none";
                }
            });

            // put the charts back in
            $.each(charts, function (i, chart) {
                origParent[i] = chart.container.parentNode;
                body.appendChild(chart.container);
            });

            // print
            window.print();

            // allow the browser to prepare before reverting
            setTimeout(function () {
                // put the charts back in
                $.each(charts, function (i, chart) {
                    origParent[i].appendChild(chart.container);
                });

                // restore all body content
                Highcharts.each(childNodes, function (node, i) {
                    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                        node.style.display = origDisplay[i];
                    }
                });
            }, 500);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I will look into it, but it looks good from what I see in jsFiddle!

Comment: Highcharts removed the files, you can use this instead of the first link better http://jsfiddle.net/q5Rzu/147/

Comment: Can you help me ? I want to print a 5 charts at a time. But I want to give a tittle on the top of the first page. How to do that ?

Answer (score 8):

The exportChart method accepts parameters so you can send it more than one chart. However, the print method does not accept any parameters. So, to print you have to specify each chart separately like chart1.print(); and chart2.print(); which prints them each separately.

There are two workarounds:

1. Printing the whole page without using Highcharts printing. Here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gd7bB/635/).
2. You could export both of the charts to a pdf file and then print form there.  Here is an example on how to [**export multiple charts to one pdf**](http://jsfiddle.net/gd7bB/639/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works in jFiddle, but on my page, this prints not only the chart but everything else on the page. I guess I could work something out using a print CSS, but is there a way to print only the charts?

Comment: That's what I intended to use if it's not possible to print multiple charts from the client side. I'll leave the question open for now, in case someone has a different solution.

Comment: The ***exportChart*** method accepts parameters so you can send it more than one chart.  However, the ***print*** method does not accept any parameters.  So, to print you have to specify each chart separately like `chart1.print();` and `chart2.print();` which prints them each separately.  The first answer I gave you does not use highcharts printing and ignored the parameters.  That's why it printed the whole page.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought from reading the Highcharts documentation. I'll put this info in your answer and accept it.