# Printing html page elements

Tags: highcharts

I have a graph in Highcharts. The page prints how it should when I click the print button.

How can I include html elements (eg. H1, div, select) from the page to the printed output.

I'm not interested in exporting to jpeg etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a new field to the export button that would print the whole page using the JS function `window.print()`:

```
Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
    text: 'Print Full Page',
    onclick: function () {
        window.print();
    }
```

Which you could also combine with a CSS media query to remove the html that you don't want to print:

```
@media print {
   …
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3GNZC/78/

If you are interested in printing multiple charts in one go, this link may interest you: [Highcharts: "Print all" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125969/highcharts-print-all-button)

Comment: Is it possible to include the HTML bellow the chart ?

Comment: It is possible, since the following javascript prints the html present in the window (Unless it is given CSS that will make it ignored when printed)